# Navigate from ViewController to RootViewController with Main Navigation tabs intact

Tags: ios, swift

This works fine:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let innerPage: subVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subSB") as! subVC
self.present(innerPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And also this does not work:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let innerPage: subVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subSB") as! subVC
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
```

Except that it removes the MainNavigation view. It just shows the specific view, but the without the MainNav. I think its because of I'm not going to the root view controller from my ViewController where I call the code?

This is how it's configured:
[image]

But how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is replaces the root view controller with subVC. If you want to retain mainNavigationVC and only to change its' root to subVC, do as follows

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let innerPage: subVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subSB") as! subVC
let mainNav: mainNavigationVC = mainNavigationVC(rootViewController: innerPage)

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainNav
```